# Is this pattern of Task queueing acceptable?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

The AsyncWorkerQueue class uses TPL Data Flow and Rx to async process and cancel work in a queue. It takes in a worker factory (Func) and executes it when its turn (or not if its scheduled to be canceled).

```
public class AsyncWorkerQueue : IDisposable
{
    private TransformBlock<TaskFactory, TaskFactory> Worker { get; set; }
    private TransformBlock<TaskFactory, TaskFactory> DirtyWorkers { get; set; }
    private IObservable<TaskFactory> StartedTasks { get; set; }
    private IObservable<TaskFactory> CompletedTasks { get; set; }
    private TaskFactory CurrentWorker { get; set; }
    private SemaphoreSlim SuspendSemaphore { get; set; }
    private Task SuspendWorker { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuspended { get; private set; }
    private CancellationTokenSource QueueWorkersToken { get; set; }
    private CancellationTokenSource SuspendToken { get; set; }
    public AsyncWorkerQueue(Action<Exception> handleException = null)
    {
        DirtyWorkers = new TransformBlock<TaskFactory, TaskFactory>(tf => tf);
        Worker = new TransformBlock<TaskFactory, TaskFactory>(tf =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (SuspendToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    tf.CancelImmediately();
                    DirtyWorkers.Post(tf);
                    return tf;
                }
                CurrentWorker = tf;
                tf.Execute();
                DirtyWorkers.Post(tf);
                tf.Worker.Wait();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            catch (Exception ex) { if (handleException != null) handleException(ex); }
            return tf;
        });
        CompletedTasks = Worker.AsObservable();
        QueueWorkersToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        StartedTasks = DirtyWorkers.AsObservable();
        SuspendSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        SuspendWorker = Task.FromResult(false);
        SuspendToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
    public Task DoWork(Func<Task> workerFactory, CancellationTokenSource source = null)
    {
        return DoWorker(workerFactory, source);
    }
    private async Task DoWorker(Func<Task> workerFactory, CancellationTokenSource source = null)
    {
        try
        {
            await SuspendWorker;
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException) {}
        QueueWorkersToken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(workerFactory, source);
        SemaphoreSlim s = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        bool isCanceled = false;
        Task sWait = s.WaitAsync(QueueWorkersToken.Token);
        ActionBlock<TaskFactory> taskWaiter = new ActionBlock<TaskFactory>(finishedTask =>
        {
            if (finishedTask.TaskId == tf.TaskId)
            {
                isCanceled = finishedTask.Worker.IsCanceled;
                s.Release();
            }
        });
        var taskWaiterObserver = taskWaiter.AsObserver();
        using (CompletedTasks.Subscribe(taskWaiterObserver))
        {
            Worker.Post(tf);
            try
            {
                await sWait;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { throw; }
            if (isCanceled)
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }
    }
    public async Task WaitCurrentWorkers(Action doWait = null, Action<Exception> handleException = null, bool cancelQueue = false)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        this.Suspend(cancelQueue);
        SemaphoreSlim s = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        Task sWait = s.WaitAsync();
        ActionBlock<TaskFactory> taskDisposer = new ActionBlock<TaskFactory>(tf =>
        {
            tf.Cancel();
            try
            {
                tf.Worker.Wait();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            catch (Exception ex) { if (handleException != null)handleException(ex); }
            if (Worker.InputCount == 0)
                s.Release();
        });
        var observer = taskDisposer.AsObserver();
        IDisposable subscriber = null;
        try
        {
            subscriber = StartedTasks.Subscribe(observer);
            if (CurrentWorker != null)
            {
                CurrentWorker.Cancel();
                try
                {
                    await CurrentWorker.Worker;
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
                catch (Exception ex) { if (handleException != null)handleException(ex); }
            }
            if (Worker.InputCount > 0 || Worker.OutputCount > 0)
                await sWait;
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            if(subscriber != null)
                subscriber.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
        {
            SuspendToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            SuspendSemaphore.Release();
            IsSuspended = false;
        }
    }
    public void Suspend(bool cancelQueueTasks = false)
    {
        if (cancelQueueTasks)
            SuspendToken.Cancel(true);
        if (!IsSuspended)
        {
            SuspendWorker = DoSuspendWorker();
            IsSuspended = true;
        }
    }
    private async Task DoSuspendWorker()
    {
        try
        {
            await SuspendSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    }
    private class TaskFactory
    {
        public Guid TaskId { get; private set; }
        private Func<Task> Factory { get; set; }
        public Task Worker { get; private set; }
        private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
        public TaskFactory(Func<Task> taskFactory, CancellationTokenSource source = null)
        {
            TaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Factory = taskFactory;
            CancellationTokenSource = source;
        }
        public void Cancel()
        {
            if(this.CancellationTokenSource != null)
                this.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel(true);
        }
        public void CancelImmediately()
        {
            this.Cancel();
            Worker = Task.FromResult(false);
        }
        public Task Execute()
        {
            Worker = Factory();
            return Worker;
        }
    }

    public async void Dispose()
    {
        if (QueueWorkersToken != null)
            QueueWorkersToken.Cancel(true);
        await WaitCurrentWorkers(cancelQueue: true);
        if (Worker != null)
            Worker.Complete();
        if (DirtyWorkers != null)
            DirtyWorkers.Complete();
    }
}
```

I also added an example class that uses AsyncWorkerQueue, this is a view model base for async loading/unloading of content.

```
public abstract class NavigationItem : BindableBase, IDisposable
{
    public NavigationData Data { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return Data.DisplayName; }
    }
    public bool IsCloseable
    {
        get { return Data.IsCloseable; }
    }
    public NavigationItem(NavigationData data)
    {
        Data = data;
        State = NavigationItemState.Unloaded;
        Close = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            Task t = Unload();
            EventHandler closed = Closed;
            if (closed != null)
                closed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        });
        LoadWorkers = new AsyncWorkerQueue(ex => this.Unload());
        UnloadWorkers = new AsyncWorkerQueue();
    }
    private AsyncWorkerQueue LoadWorkers { get; set; }
    private AsyncWorkerQueue UnloadWorkers { get; set; }
    private NavigationItemState state;
    public NavigationItemState State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref state, value))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsUnloading);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsUnloaded);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsLoading);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsLoaded);
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsUnloading { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Unloading; } }
    public bool IsUnloaded { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Unloaded; } }
    public bool IsLoading { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Loading; } }
    public bool IsLoaded { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Loaded; } }
    public event EventHandler Unloading;
    public event EventHandler Unloaded;
    public event EventHandler Loading;
    public event EventHandler Loaded;
    public event EventHandler<NavigationItemAddedEventArgs> NavigationItemAdded;
    public ICommand Close { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler Closed;
    private void RaiseUnloading()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Unloading;
        var evt = Unloading;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private void RaiseUnloaded()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Unloaded;
        var evt = Unloaded;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private void RaiseLoading()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Loading;
        var evt = Loading;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private void RaiseLoaded()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Loaded;
        var evt = Loaded;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    protected void AddNavigationItem(NavigationItem item)
    {
        var evt = NavigationItemAdded;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, new NavigationItemAddedEventArgs(item));
    }
    protected abstract Task DoLoad(CancellationToken token);
    public async Task Load()
    {
        if (State == NavigationItemState.Loading || State == NavigationItemState.Loaded)
            await Unload();
        var cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await LoadWorkers.DoWork(() => DoLoadWorker(cancelationTokenSource.Token), cancelationTokenSource);
    }
    private async Task DoLoadWorker(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await UnloadWorkers.WaitCurrentWorkers();
        UnloadWorkers.Start();
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        RaiseLoading();
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await DoLoad(token);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        RaiseLoaded();
    }
    protected abstract Task DoUnload();
    public Task Unload()
    {
        return UnloadWorkers.DoWork(() => DoUnloadWorker());
    }
    private async Task DoUnloadWorker()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        RaiseUnloading();
        await LoadWorkers.WaitCurrentWorkers(cancelQueue: true);
        try
        {
            await DoUnload();
            RaiseUnloaded();
        }
        catch { throw; }
        finally
        {
            LoadWorkers.Start();
        }
    }
    ~NavigationItem()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (LoadWorkers != null)
            LoadWorkers.Dispose();
        if (UnloadWorkers != null)
            UnloadWorkers.Dispose();
    }
}
public abstract class NavigationItem<T> : NavigationItem
{
    public NavigationItem(NavigationData data)
        : base(data)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; private set; }
    protected abstract Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItems(CancellationToken token);
    protected override async Task DoLoad(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var items = await GetItems(token);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (items != null)
        {
            DispatcherLocator.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    protected override Task DoUnload()
    {
        DispatcherLocator.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Items.Clear());
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

Lastly I have a lighter weight implementation of this queuing concept which is less generic and relies on two Tasks that block each-other to prevent critical logic from being executed simultaneously. (We don't want to Load and Unload at the same time). This uses a pure async/await pattern.

```
public abstract class NavigationItem : BindableBase
{
    public NavigationData Data { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return Data.DisplayName; }
    }
    public bool IsCloseable
    {
        get { return Data.IsCloseable; }
    }
    public NavigationItem(NavigationData data)
    {
        Data = data;
        State = NavigationItemState.Unloaded;
        Close = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            Task t = Unload();
            EventHandler closed = Closed;
            if (closed != null)
                closed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        });
    }
    private Task LoadWorker { get; set; }
    private Task UnloadWorker { get; set; }
    private NavigationItemState state;
    public NavigationItemState State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref state, value))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsUnloading);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsUnloaded);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsLoading);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsLoaded);
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsUnloading { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Unloading; } }
    public bool IsUnloaded { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Unloaded; } }
    public bool IsLoading { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Loading; } }
    public bool IsLoaded { get { return State == NavigationItemState.Loaded; } }
    public event EventHandler Unloading;
    public event EventHandler Unloaded;
    public event EventHandler Loading;
    public event EventHandler Loaded;
    public event EventHandler<NavigationItemAddedEventArgs> NavigationItemAdded;
    public ICommand Close { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler Closed;
    private void RaiseUnloading()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Unloading;
        var evt = Unloading;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private void RaiseUnloaded()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Unloaded;
        var evt = Unloaded;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private void RaiseLoading()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Loading;
        var evt = Loading;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private void RaiseLoaded()
    {
        State = NavigationItemState.Loaded;
        var evt = Loaded;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    protected void AddNavigationItem(NavigationItem item)
    {
        var evt = NavigationItemAdded;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, new NavigationItemAddedEventArgs(item));
    }
    private async Task WaitLoad()
    {
        if (LoadWorker != null)
        {
            try
            {
                await LoadWorker;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { } //task canceled
            catch { Task unloader = Unload(); }
        }
    }
    private async Task WaitUnload()
    {
        if (UnloadWorker != null)
            await UnloadWorker;
    }
    protected abstract Task DoLoad(CancellationToken token);
    public async Task Load()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        if (State == NavigationItemState.Loading || State == NavigationItemState.Loaded)
            await Unload();
        else if(State == NavigationItemState.Unloading)
            await WaitUnload();
        RaiseLoading();
        LoadCancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        LoadWorker = DoLoadWorker();
        await WaitLoad();
    }
    private CancellationTokenSource LoadCancelationTokenSource { get; set; }
    private CancellationToken LoadCancelationToken { get { return LoadCancelationTokenSource.Token; } }
    private async Task DoLoadWorker()
    {
        LoadCancelationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await DoLoad(LoadCancelationToken);
        LoadCancelationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        RaiseLoaded();
    }
    protected abstract Task DoUnload();
    public async Task Unload()
    {
        await WaitUnload();
        RaiseUnloading();
        UnloadWorker = DoUnloadWorker();
        await WaitUnload();
    }
    private async Task DoUnloadWorker()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        if (LoadWorker != null)
            LoadCancelationTokenSource.Cancel(true);
        await WaitLoad();
        await DoUnload();
        RaiseUnloaded();
    }
}
public abstract class NavigationItem<T> : NavigationItem
{
    public NavigationItem(NavigationData data)
        : base(data)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; private set; }
    protected abstract Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItems(CancellationToken token);
    protected override async Task DoLoad(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var items = await GetItems(token);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (items != null)
        {
            DispatcherLocator.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    protected override Task DoUnload()
    {
        DispatcherLocator.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Items.Clear());
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TaskFactory
```

That's a pretty confusing name, since there already is a [`TaskFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory) class in TPL, with different meaning.

---

```
new TransformBlock<TaskFactory, TaskFactory>(tf => tf)
```

You don't need a `TransformBlock` for this, you can use `BufferBlock` instead.

---

```
Action<Exception> handleException
```

I would expect `handleException` to be a `bool`. A better name for this would be `exceptionHandler`.

---

```
StartedTasks = DirtyWorkers.AsObservable();
```

Doesn't `DirtyWorkers` also contain workers that were canceled before they could be started?

---

```
try
{
    await sWait;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException) { throw; }
```

I you wrote just `await sWait;`, it would work the same.

---

I find the whole system of `transformBlock.AsObservable().Subscribe(actionBlock.AsObserver())`, where `actionBlock` checks for id, overcomplicated.

One way to simplify this is to have `TaskFactory` expose a `Completed` `Task`. You can then `await` it, or use `ContinueWith()` on it.

---

Instead of `SemaphoreSlim` that starts with 0, is `await`ed once and `Release`d once, you could use `TaskCompletionSource`.

---

```
await Task.Yield();
```

what is the purpose of this? I don't see any reason for it here.